display appears out of bounds like I'm zoomed in
Using this:
xrandr \
--output DVI-0 --mode 1280x1024 --primary \
--output HDMI-1-2 --right-of DVI-0 --mode 1600x900 --scale-from 1920x1080 \
--output HDMI-2 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as HDMI-1-2

Basically the goal is to get this:

DVI-0 is just the primary display displaying at native res 1280x1024 in the OFFICE.
HDMI-2 is a big TV in a different room (living room) which should be operated at native res 1920x1080.
HDMI-1-2 is a wide monitor in OFFICE. It should be operated at 1600x900 because that's it's max res, but should MIRROR HDMI-2. This requires it to be scaled and I realize it will lose some pixels.

Currently it works fine EXCEPT that HDMI-1-2 is cut off on the bottom. So the HDMI-2 TV works fine and I can see everything there, but the bottom of that is missing from HDMI-1-2. How to fix this?

check out the xrandr options for "underscan" and see if you can resolve it that way. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr
